# Postgres - update a table with a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

At the moment I am using the following query:

```
SELECT *,
       concat_ws(',', column_1::text, column_2::text, column_3::text) AS column_4
 FROM table_name;`
```

But I want it to update the table `(table_name)`, can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what do you want the update to be?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: you literally want to change the table name of your database?  any application shouldn't be granted such a privilege...only CRUD operations...usually

Comment: No i don't want to change the table name, just update it with column_4 which is a column i create with the above query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like that. If you want update other column just replace the column name after `set` command.

I also recommend you tu use a `where` clause

```
update table_name
set  column_1 =concat_ws(',', column_1::text, column_2::text, column_3::text)
```

**EDIT**

Create the new column and after run the update

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_4 character varying(250) NULL;

    update table_name
    set  column_4 =concat_ws(',', column_1::text, column_2::text, column_3::text)
```

Comment: Yes but I don't want to update column_1, I want to create a new column (column_4). Thanks

Comment: Can you also help me with updating the same table with an order by column_4? Thanks is advance

Comment: I don't understand why updating with order by, because order by organize the result for query. You don't need order the update statement.

Comment: sorry i want to order the same table by column_5

Comment: just repeat the sequency.